# Azure app fabric web role deployment failing

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, appfabric, azure-appfabric

I am deploying to local azure compute emulator.  It goes into a loop displaying: Role state Unknown and Destroyed.  I can deploy the same exact code to azure cloud with no issues, but it fails in the local deployment.  I checked the fusion log to see if there is any assembly load issues with no avail.  How can I chase down such an issue?

Answer (score 0):

OK. It turns out I copied the web.config from the earlier version and it brought the old version of DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener and targetFramework.  I guess, this is a pretty common pattern of mistake.  Once I fixed them by copying them from a health project, it worked like charm.